# verification email and email has not been verified message after register

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

I create a menu login and register with email verification . but none the less I want if the email has not been verified will display the message " Your email has not been verified " what should I add to my script ... ?

ex :

active = 1 ( already verified )

active = 0 ( not verified )

controllers:

```
public function index($param='')
{
    if($param == 'error')
        $param = 'Incorrect username or password';

    $data = array('title'=>'Login', 
                  'message'=>$param, 
                  'isi' => 'login/vlogin', 
                  'base_url'=>base_url());
    $this->load->view('layout/wrapper', $data); 
}


public function do_login(){


    $data = $this->input->post(null,true);
    $is_login = $this->db->get_where('user',array(
                            'email'=>$data['email'],
                            'password'=>$data['password'],
                            'active'=> 1
                             ))->row();      
    if($is_login){
        $session_set = array(

            'is_login'  => true,
            'firstname' => $is_login->firstname,
            'lastname'  => $is_login->lastname,
            'jkl'       => $is_login->jkl,  
            'id'        => $is_login->id,               
            'lastlogin' => $is_login->lastlogin
        );
        $this->db->update('user',array('lastlogin'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s')),array('id'=>$is_login->id));
        $this->session->set_userdata($session_set);
        redirect('homepage/homepage/menu');
    }else{
        redirect('login/login/index/error');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check first if user credentials are correct and then check whether email is verified or not.

So, you can try this:

```
public function do_login() {

    $data = $this->input->post(null, true);

    $user = $this->db->get_where('user', array(
        'email'=>$data['email'],
        'password'=>$data['password']
         ))->row();

    if ($user) {    //User exists
        if ($user->active == 1) {   //User exists and his email is verified
            $session_set = array(
                'is_login'  => true,
                'firstname' => $user->firstname,
                'lastname'  => $user->lastname,
                'jkl'       => $user->jkl,  
                'id'        => $user->id,               
                'lastlogin' => $user->lastlogin
            );

            $this->db->update('user', array('lastlogin'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s')), array('id'=>$user->id));
            $this->session->set_userdata($session_set);
            redirect('homepage/homepage/menu');   

        } else {    //User exists BUT his email is NOT verified

            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Your email is not verified yet');
            //You have to capture and show the flash message in view

            redirect('login/login/index/error');
        }
    } else {    //User does NOT exist at all

        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'The combination of username and/or password was incorrect. Please, try again.');
        //You have to capture and show the flash message in view

        redirect('login/login/index/error');
    }
}
```

And in your view put something like:

```
<?php if ($this->session->flashdata('message')) : ?>
<p class="someErrorClass"><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('message'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want this to appear whenever the particular user, whom you sent a verification email to, accesses your site again.
To my knowledge you would have to look into placing a cookies on his/her machine and checking for it's existence whenever a any user accesses your site. Hope that helps you along the way.

Comment: thanks @Charles Haughey but I do not know how to edit